# Find events recurring every week

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the **keys** that are recurring at a weekly cadence in a set of events, similar to the following:

```
_index          _time             key
0  2018-12-01T23:59:56.000+0000    mike
1  2018-12-04T23:59:36.000+0000    mike
2  2018-12-13T23:59:05.000+0000    mike
3  2018-12-20T23:57:45.000+0000    mike
4  2018-12-31T23:57:21.000+0000    jerry
5  2018-12-31T23:57:15.000+0000    david
6  2018-12-31T23:55:13.000+0000    tom
7  2018-12-31T23:54:28.000+0000    mike
8  2018-12-31T23:54:21.000+0000    john
```

I have tried creating groups by date, using the following:

`df = [g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='_time',freq='W'), as_index=False)]`

but have been unable to find the intersection of the various groups using: `set.intersection()`, `reduce` & `pd.merge`, and `df.join`

Comment: What should your output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we `groupby` `key` then check whether this name show in all weeks

```
s=df['_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%w').groupby(df['key']).nunique()
nweek=df['_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%w').nunique()
s[s==nweek]
key
mike    4
Name: _time, dtype: int64
```